# What is difference between fully declare form control and not in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I hope you will teach me what is the difference between "a","b","c" FormControls in FormGroup.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    a: [{ value: this.a }],
    b: [this.b],
    c: new FormControl({ value: this.c }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> new FormControl({ value: this.c })

Instantiate a `FormControl`, with an initial value(here in this case value is `c`).
Generally, we use this kind of initialization in case of when you need individual formControl may be without formGroup, but of course you can use it with formGroup as well.

> b: [this.b] and a: [{ value: this.a }],

This again signifies formControl within the formGroup with some initial value.

Apart from this there are many more parameters are there which you can use with formControl, like validators etc. for that I would suggest better to read the documentation.

For ref.

- https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl